# How can I convert 1D array from numbers to 2D array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array from numbers like this :

```
$array = array (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);
```

I tried to convert it to 2D using two for loops but i failed. Is it better to try with foreach loop , or it can be done with for-s ?

I wanna make something like this:

```
$array = array (array (1,2,3,4), array(5,6,7,8), array(9,10,11,12));
```

Comment: no, array_chunk helped :) it was a bit difficult to sort 2D array , and i must make it first 1D , sort it and then convert it again to 2D :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason I'm posting an answer is that a question like this and the availability of [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) may not be very intuitive:

```
$array = array_chunk($array, 4);
```